# How to fetch an image from a url to an arrayList

Tags: java, android, gridview, arraylist

I'm trying to show images that are read from a url, they are more than an image so I had to put all of them in an arraylist and then make the images display in a gridview, for some reason it's not showing anything, the gridview is completely blank, please advise what am I doing wrong.

BottomSheetDialog_Smiles.java

```
Communicator.getInstance().on("subscribe start", new Emitter.Listener() {

        @Override
        public void call(Object... args) {
            try{

JSONDictionary response = (JSONDictionary) args[0];
String str = response.get("emojiPack").toString();
JSONArray emojies = new JSONArray(str);

for(int i=0;i<emojies.length();i++){

JSONObject response2 = (JSONObject) 
emojies.getJSONObject(i);

emojiModel = new EmojiModel((String) response2.get("urlFile"));
emojiUrl = emojiModel.getEmojiFile();
Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(emojiUrl);
JSONDictionary t = JSONDictionary.fromString(response2.toString());
emojiModel.init(t);
emojieModels.add(new EmojiModel(emojiUrl));
                }

EmojiAdapter emojiAdapter = new EmojiAdapter(getApplicationContext(), 
emojieModels);
gridView2.setAdapter(emojiAdapter);


            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });
    EmojiAdapter emojiAdapter = new EmojiAdapter(getApplicationContext(), 
    emojieModels);
    gridView2.setAdapter(emojiAdapter);
```

EmojiAdapter.java

```
public class EmojiAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<EmojiModel> {

Context context;
ArrayList<EmojiModel> list = new ArrayList<>();

public EmojiAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<EmojiModel> list) {
    super(context, R.layout.smiles_items_layout, list);
    this.context = context;
    this.list = list;
}
@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater o = 
(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View v = o.inflate(R.layout.gifts_layout_2, parent , false);

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.smile_image_view);


imageView.setImageResource(Integer.parseInt((list.get(position)).urlFile));

    return v;
    }
}
```

EmojiModel.Java

```
public class EmojiModel {
private int id;
private int price;
public String urlFile;

public EmojiModel(String urlFile) {
    this.urlFile=urlFile;
}

public String getEmojiFile() {
    return urlFile;
}

public void init(JSONDictionary data){
    try{
        urlFile = (String) data.get("urlFile");
        id = Integer.parseInt((String) data.get("id"));
        price = Integer.parseInt((String) data.get("price"));

    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Can you share that image url with me?

Comment: These images are still on local server but you can explain on any url if you would like to

Answer (score 1, accepted):

obviously this line of code wont work :

```
imageView.setImageResource(Integer.parseInt((list.get(position)).urlFile));
```

instead of that just use glide or piccaso to load pics.
first add this line to your gradle file :

```
  implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.5.0'
  annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.5.0'
```

then instead of above line ,just write :
Glide.with(context).load(list.get(position)).urlFile).into(imageView);

also the picaso library is pretty same

---

also change your adapter in this way :

```
public class EmojiAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    Context context;
    ArrayList<EmojiModel> list = new ArrayList<>();

    public EmojiAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<EmojiModel> list) {
        super(context, R.layout.smiles_items_layout, list);
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;
    }
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater o =
                (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View v = o.inflate(R.layout.gifts_layout_2, parent , false);

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.smile_image_view);


        imageView.setImageResource(Integer.parseInt((list.get(position)).urlFile));

        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
}
```

Comment: This totally makes sense, however for some reason it is still not showing any images

Comment: I've updated the code and I guess that all of the code that you need to look at

Comment: change this line in this way : Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(emojiUrl).into(yourImageView);

Comment: you should use that line in your adapter. instead of imageView.setImageResource(Integer.parseInt((list.get(position)).urlFile));

Comment: yes I've changed it in my adapter to Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(list.get(position).getEmojiFile()).into(imageView); but still not working

Comment: you havnt updated that so i thought u havent changed that line :D

Comment: put a log before Picasso.with... : Log.d("TAG",list.get(position).fileUrl) and see do u receive any url here?

Comment: 01-14 12:52:12.001 697-1164/? E/voice: voice_is_in_call_rec_stream: input stream is NULL
01-14 12:52:12.002 697-1164/? E/ACDB-LOADER: Error: ACDB AudProc vol returned = -19
01-14 12:52:12.025 697-1164/? E/ACDB-LOADER: Error: ACDB audproc returned = -19
01-14 12:52:12.025 697-1164/? E/ACDB-LOADER: Error: ACDB AudProc vol returned = -19
01-14 12:52:12.025 697-1164/? E/ACDB-LOADER: Error: ACDB AFE returned = -19

Comment: its not the log result i guess

Comment: okay let me explain something that might help you out help me, the arraylist that I am using is returning 3 values: id, price and url, however I'm trying to display the url only, would that be the problem ?

Comment: NO thats not a problem. the important thing now is that you check that if the url field is returning null or not. log that

Comment: This is way more complicated than it has to be. Simply put a breakpoint at the end of the `EmojiAdapter` constructor. Run the app in debug mode. At the break point inspect the contents of `list`.

Comment: believe it or not, I've tried that already and it's returning the url requested from the server, however, when I put breakpoints on the getView method, they are not accessed !!

Comment: have u added Internet-Permission in your app? :D

Comment: If the breakpoint you set is never reached, then the problem lies elsewhere. `getView()` is never called. Verify that `EmojiAdapter` is indeed being created and set to your `ListView`.

Comment: but if the getView method never calls, how could you check that the urlField is fine?

Comment: I mean the url get called from the server and goes into the arraylist but this has nothing to do with the getView

Comment: do this please : put this line in your getView : Log.d("TAG",list.get(position).fileUrl)  and see if any results prints in logCat or not.

Comment: it does not, because the getView method is not accessed

Comment: i added the adapter code. please check that if this code works

Comment: I've tried it out, still not working.
I managed to get the code go inside the getView, but still nothing appears at all inside the gridView

Comment: check if emojieModels is null before u pass it to your adapter or not. and please replace your adapter completely with my code

Comment: I did replace the adapter completely with your code, and now nothing is showing still, and regarding the emojieModels it comes up with size = 2

Comment: Also, please bare in mind that your code doesn't include downloading the image using picasso

Comment: Bro, I got it sorted out, finnaaaallllyyyyy,,,and that's because of you as you gave me the main idea of Picasso and how to debug this little thing,,,,thanks a lot (Y)

Comment: Im glad u could do it finally 

Answer (score 1):

Use Picasso in Adapter to show image

```
   @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater o =
 (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View v = o.inflate(R.layout.gifts_layout_2, parent , false);

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.smile_image_view);

        Picasso.with(getApplicationContext()).load(list.get(position).getEmojiUrl()).into(imageView);

        return v;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I've tried the above code but still not showing any images